# How to prevent alpha blend from erasing itself?

Tags: transparency

If I set alpha to alpha blend, then the model erases itself wherever there is alpha. Is there any way to prevent this? (Also, this is not for a render, so I'd prefer to avoid doing separating things into different objects etc)

[image]

Comment: Probably sorting issue. Try using "Alpha Hashed" instead of "Alpha Blend", or set the render engine to Cycles and use the Render view.

Comment: Alpha hashed has delay, and noise which does not go away. I want to be able to preview the result in real time as much as possible.

Comment: If there were a way to do that, it would just be the default and people wouldn't muck around with alpha blend and alpha hashed and stuff.

Comment: Try enabling/disabling "Backface Culling" and/or "Show Backface" (using alpha-blend) and see if that helps.